# Parsing a tei XML with golang

Tags: xml, go

I need to parse a tei XML file with golang. I tried using the encoding/xml unmarshaller. Here is the example:
http://play.golang.org/p/h0k-4IjngY

Problems:

1. Even if tei file is not valid and the xml is valid the example returns me nothing. If I remove line 23 `<TEI>` (so xml is not anymore valid), the example prints something.
2. How can I have the Line struct a string containing the content of `<l>` element?
3. In the Page struct I need the value of `n` attribute, how do I achieve this?

Is unmarshalling the right way to parse these kinds of files or nokogiri would be a better solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to read this XML using [xml.Unmarshal()](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshal).

The problem is that the XML structure is the following:

```
<TEI>
    <text>
        <sp>
        </sp>
        <sp>
        </sp>
    </text>
</TEI>
```

And your Go structure is the following:

```
Page
    []Speak
```

**There is one missing layer.** Your `Page` might match the `<TEI>` or `<text>` element, but not both. It works for you if you remove the `<TEI>` element because then `Page` can match `<text>` and its contents.

**Solution:**

Add another wrapper like this:

```
type Text struct {
    Txt Page `xml:"text"`
}
```

And of course parse a value of this type:

```
var p Text
err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &p)
```

Try it your modified code on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/DuMW9GLHnS).